# cURL to show response headers after submiting a file

Tags: curl

I post file to url and would like to read all headers output in curl console. What parameter should I add?

```
curl -F file=@"c:\Word.docx" http://do.convertapi.com/Word2Pdf > output.pdf
```

Comment: Looking for `-I`? Or `-D` if you want to dump the headers into a file

Comment: If I add -I before -F i get error: Warning: You can only select one HTTP request! curl: option -F: is badly used here curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

Comment: `I` sends a HEAD request and `F` sends POST, hence the conflict. You need `i` as it just adds headers to command line output and doesn't affect the request. (answered below)

Comment: Did you want the HTTP response body written to `output.pdf`, but the headers displayed in the console?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use `-i`

From the cURL manual

```
 -i, --include       Include protocol headers in the output (H/F)
```

Note also:

```
-I, --head          Show document info only
```

The first will show headers, followed by body. The second will send a HEAD request so can't be used in your example as you're POSTing data.

**Edit**

The header output using `-i` is echoed to stdout, the same as the request body so directing the response into a PDF file will create an invalid PDF.

So I suggest instead you use `-v` which will be much noisier, but will show headers on command line when directing stdout to file, because verbose output goes to stderr.

Comment: if you have chance try to execute curl -i -F file=@"c:\Word.docx" http://do.convertapi.com/Word2Pdf > output.pdf
and you will not get any response headers in curl console.

Comment: you are sending the response headers into your PDF, which will also make it an invalid PDF

Comment: How to get and save response file and get output headers in curl console?

Comment: I get you. just updated my answer. `-v` may be better for your case

Answer (score 5):

In [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) and [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) systems the following submits the request, writing the response headers to the console and saving the response body to `output.pdf`:

```shell
curl -F file=@"c:\Word.docx" http://do.convertapi.com/Word2Pdf \
--output output.pdf --dump-header /dev/fd/1 --silent | tail -n +2
```

### Explanation

The `--output output.pdf` option outputs the results to `output.pdf`.

> ```
> -o, --output <file>
>        Write output to <file> instead of stdout.
> ```

The `--dump-header /dev/fd/1` option writes the HTTP status line (e.g. `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`) and response headers to standard output (i.e. the console).  The `--dump-header` option dumps the headers to the given file. `/dev/fd/1` is the [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) for stdout, so anything written to it is output to the console (or to wherever the standard output is piped or redirected).

> ```console
> -D, --dump-header <filename>
>        (HTTP FTP) Write the received protocol headers to the specified file.
> ```

The `--silent` option makes it so that just the headers are output, and not the progress bar.

> ```
> -s, --silent
>        Silent  or  quiet  mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for,
>        potentially even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.
> ```

The result of `curl` is [piped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) to [tail](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) command `tail -n +2`, which discards the first line of content, which is the HTTP status line (e.g. `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`).  If you want or don't mind having the status line as well as the headers, this `tail` pipe portion can be omitted.

> ```
> -n, --lines=[+]NUM
>        output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use
>        -n +NUM to output starting with line NUM
> ```

#### Example

```
$ curl http://www.example.com --output test.html \
--dump-header /dev/fd/1 --silent | tail -n +2

Age: 466166
Cache-Control: max-age=604800
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 27 Oct 2021 16:49:42 GMT
Etag: "3147526947+gzip+ident"
Expires: Wed, 03 Nov 2021 16:49:42 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
Server: ECS (chb/0286)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 1256
```

Comment: A variation on this solution to not need files: `curl http://www.example.com --output /dev/null --dump-header /dev/stdout --silent`

Comment: Alternatively: `curl -D - -o 'out.html' -S -s` or `curl -D - -o 'out.html' -S -s 1>log.txt 2>&1`